# Modify automatically generated resources in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I'm using terraform to deploy some CloudFormation stacks. In this process, several S3 buckets are created (automatically based on the template, and not defined in Terraform). When I want to destroy these stacks, because these S3 buckets are not empty, the stack destroy process would fail. In Terraform, I can set `force_destroy = true` for resources with definition. How do I add this flag to the automatically generated/managed S3 bucket?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add this flag to the automatically generated/managed S3 bucket?

You don't. CloudFormation does not have any equivalent of `force_destroy = true` from TF. You have to develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) using a lambda function, as for example, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383470/can-i-force-cloudformation-to-delete-non-empty-s3-bucket).

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot import these automatically created buckets into terraform to update and add ```force_destroy = true``` to them? Creating a custom resource looks complicated for a simple task like this 